# Violacion de segmento

Tags: c, punteros, manejo-de-memoria, struct

El problema es que al ejecutar el programa produce una violación de segmento y no logro encontrar el por qué. El objetivo es que llegue hasta la línea de `"error detectado en la tabla"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1000

struct data_unit{
   int data;
   struct data_unit *next;
 };
 typedef struct data_unit unit, *unit_ptr;

 void function(unit_ptr table){

      int y;
      for (y = 0; y <SIZE-1; y++)
      {
           table[y].data = y;
           table[y].next = &table[y + 1];
      }
      table[SIZE - 1].data = SIZE - 1;
  }

 int check(unit_ptr table){

    int y;
    for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++)
    {
         if ((table[y].data + 1) != table[y].next->data){
                return 1;
         }
    }
    return 0;
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
         unit_ptr buf;

         buf = (unit_ptr)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(unit_ptr));
         function(buf);
         if (check(buf))
         {
             printf("Error detectado en tabla\n");
         }
         free(buf);

         return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenido sobre es.stackoverflow.com ! Puede anadir el mensaje de error que obtiene ?

Comment: Esto no funciona así. Si alguna respuesta soluciona tu problema la marcas como solución y listo... en la pregunta **no deben** ir soluciones.

Comment: @eferion la respuesta no es del todo correcta como explique en los comentarios por eso no la marque como solucionada donde puedo ponerlo para que quede bien claro?

Comment: editando la pregunta para añadir las respuestas desde luego no. Si una respuesta no es correcta debes comentar dicha respuesta y será responsabilidad del propietario de dicha respuesta adecuarla correctamente. Si, por otro lado, ves que es tu pregunta la que no está bien redactada o es incompleta lo que tienes que hcaer es editar tu pregunta para añadir la información que falta o eliminar ambigüedades

Comment: ya comente la respuesta en los comentarios argumentando porque estaba mal

Comment: entonces lo correcto seria marcarla como solucionada aunque este mal?

Comment: No, si está mal no la tienes que marcar como solución e incluso tampoco deberías votarla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu programa tiene, básicamente, dos errores:

## No reserva bien la memoria

```
buf = (unit_ptr)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(unit_ptr));
```

Se supone que pretendes crear una reserva para `SIZE` elementos de tamaño `unit` y lo que haces es hacer `SIZE` reservas de tamaño `unit_ptr`.

El problema aquí no es tanto que el tamaño de `unit` no sea el mismo que el de `unit_ptr` sino que el tamaño de este último es menor... luego la reserva de memoria que te da el sistema es insuficiente para tus propósitos.

Lo correcto aquí sería hacer:

```
buf = (unit_ptr)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(unit));
```

## Cuidado con las iteraciones

```
for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++)
{
     if ((table[y].data + 1) != table[y].next->data){
            return 1;
     }
}
```

Cuando este bucle llegue a `y=SIZE-1` (que será el último elemento de la lista)...

¿A dónde apunta `table[y].next`?

La respuesta es simple: Como la lista la has creado con `calloc`,  que resetea todos los bytes a 0, `tabla[SIZE-1].next` apuntará a 0 y, como es de esperar, esa posición de memoria no pertenece a tu programa.

Lo que sucede aquí es que el Sistema Operativo detecta que tu programa accede a memoria que no le pertenece y mata tu aplicación para evitar que corrompa memoria de otros procesos (o del propio Sistema Operativo).

Tienes que reducir el rango de iteración:

```
for (y = 0; y < SIZE - 1; y++)
{
     if ((table[y].data + 1) != table[y].next->data){
            return 1;
     }
}
```

Si ejecutas el código con estos cambios verás que el programa no se muere pero que tampoco muestra el mensaje de error que has puesto en el `main`... puedes comprobar que llega hasta el final *forzando* algun error en la tabla:

```
function(buf);
buf[SIZE-1].data = 0;
if (check(buf))
```

Comment: buf[SIZE-1]->data=0; no seria buf[SIZE-1].data = 0;

Comment: @WOLD26 sí, perdona, cosas de copiar y pegar

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no explicas que quieres hacer.
Ahora bien viendo el código se aprecian dos errores:

(1). El problema más fuerte radica en la línea donde dice:

buf = (unit_ptr)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(**unit_ptr**));

Aquí **calloc** genera un arreglo de tamaño SIZE lo cual esta bien pero el tamaño de cada de uno de los elementos del arreglo es tan grande como un unit_ptr (del tamaño de un apuntador) debería ser del tamaño de la memoria a la que apunta un unit_ptr es decir unit.

buf = (unit_ptr)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(**unit**));

(2). En el ciclo de la función **function** se esta yendo de 0 a SIZE-2 esto por que dice:

for (y = 0; y < **SIZE - 1**; y++)

Lo malo es que no se esta inicializando el elemento **table[SIZE-1]** por que la iteración solo llego a **SIZE-2**.

Esto tiene repercusiones hasta la función **check** por que hay si se esta iterando hasta el elemento **table[SIZE-1]** y como ese elemento no se inicializo pues falla la ejecución.

Aquí la solución es cambiar el ciclo de la función **function** para que itere todos los elementos del arreglo. Es decir hay que dejar

for (y = 0; y < **SIZE**; y++)

Con esto ya no sale el error en tiempo de ejecución, con esto verás solo lo que tu mismo has puesto con la leyenda **Error detectado en la tabla**

Comment: Me confundieron los typedef, en la primera estoy de acuerdo seria como hacer sizeof(struct data_unit) pero en la segunda creo que deberia ser en la funcion check en el cilo for SIZE-1

Comment: Al iterar en function &table[y+1] en la ultima iteracion y vale 999 si le sumo 1 vale 1000 pero como empieza en cero estaria accediendo al elemento 1001 que aunque se ejecute el printf del main creo que seria incorrecto

Comment: @WOLD26 es correcto amigo acceder al 1001 también sería incorrecto. La segunda solución es mejor, ahora que la veo me doy cuenta del porque la asignación table[SIZE - 1].data = SIZE - 1;  fue colocada al final de function.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo final corregido quedaria asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1000

struct data_unit{
   int data;
   struct data_unit *next;
 };
 typedef struct data_unit unit, *unit_ptr;

 void function(unit_ptr table){

      int y;
      for (y = 0; y < SIZE - 1; y++)
      {
           table[y].data = y;
           table[y].next = &table[y + 1];
      }
      table[SIZE - 1].data = SIZE - 1;
  }

 int check(unit_ptr table){

    int y;
    for (y = 0; y < SIZE -1; y++)
    {
         if ((table[y].data + 1) != table[y].next->data){
                return 1;
         }
    }
    return 0;
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
         unit_ptr buf;

         buf = (unit_ptr)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(unit));
         function(buf);
         if (check(buf))
         {
             printf("Error detectado en tabla\n");
         }
         free(buf);

         return 0;
 }
```